# Symfony2 on remote server shows errors

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

today I was uploaded Symfony2 to remote server and I was get below error....

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)' in
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', NULL, Array) #1
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=127....',
>   'root', NULL, Array) #2
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', NULL,
>   Array) #3
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() #4
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() #5
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(328):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->det in
>   /partner/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 103

But my MySQL user in parameters.yml is different from "root" and I created database schema successfully by CGI. Why Symfony2 trying to connect "root", when user is different?

Comment: can you post your `paramteres.yml` file

Comment: yeah
http://pastebin.com/ntg8aTRT

Comment: did you try to connect to db trough some 3rd party client? did you create database?

Comment: yeah, from php CGI console I successfully created database schema

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your environment on you app.php (or app_dev.php) will dictate which configuration Symfony will load. If you are in a production mode (prod), All your configuration will be overidden by whatever is in your app/config/config_prod.yml.

You may have some connexion details there that are overriding what is in your config.yml ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons.

First, your **parameters.yml** on remote server is different. It's overriden when you did **composer.phar install**, if you did of course and there is a task which copies **parameters.yml.dist** to new **parameters.yml** file. It's because, usually parameters.yml file is ignored in version control systems.

Second, you need to look at your **config.yml**, **config_*.yml** files. **config_*.yml** files override your **config.yml** file. So ther maybe database connection parameters hardcoded, not getting from **parameters.yml**. You should look following parameters. Specifically **user**, **password** field. Here it's hardcoded as you can see. Not reading from **parameters.yml** file.

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:   default
    types:
        # A collection of custom types
        # Example
        some_custom_type:
            class:                Acme\HelloBundle\MyCustomType
            commented:            true
    # If enabled all tables not prefixed with sf2_ will be ignored by the schema
    # tool. This is for custom tables which should not be altered automatically.
    #schema_filter:        ^sf2_

    connections:
        # A collection of different named connections (e.g. default, conn2, etc)
        default:
            dbname:               ~
            host:                 localhost
            port:                 ~
            user:                 root
            password:             ~
            charset:              ~
            path:                 ~
            memory:               ~
```

Comment: all is okay on remote server, nothing is hardcoded :( symfony still shows connection error

Comment: Would like to look at config.yml, config_dev.yml, config_prod.yml, and parameters.yml file on your server not the local.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was cleared cache and everything working fine.